# Select which audio to play on Dual Audio Video

Tags: html, html5-video

iam using html5 to watch a dual audio video:

```
 <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

, but the problem is that i cant switch audio and i really need to change the audio , can u guys give me any idea of how to do it?

Thanks in advance